# Save an Object using JPA without knowing the parent object

Tags: java, database, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 entities in my JPA repository, Student and Teacher. When I find a student using find method, I want corresponding teacher to get populated as well. But, when I save a Student object, I only have corresponding `teacher_id`, I do not have whole corresponding Teacher object. I could do a `findById` using `teacher_id`, but that is turning out to be costly, since I have many Student objects to save and each save will result in 2 DB calls.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="teacher_id")
private Teacher teacher;
```

Comment: You probably want to set use a reference there, e.g. via `Entity.getReference( Teacher.class, teacherId)`.

Comment: No, there are no two calls for every save, unless you mutate some Teacher object. Just lookup the Teacher by id and set it as reference - usually JPA will even cache that Teacher objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments indicate, I would choose to make a new call and load the whole Teacher entity, assign it to the Student entity and then save it. Think that you will need this if you have business constraints such as a maximum of students per Teacher.

That being said, to answer your question, you could add a new method to your JpaRepository with a custom insert @Query. Something similar to what is explained here:

https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-insert

Something similar to this:

```
@Transactional
public void insertWithTeacherId(Student student, long teacher_id) {
    entityManager.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO student (id, teacher_id) VALUES (?,?)")
      .setParameter(1, student.getId())
      .setParameter(2, teacher_id)
      .executeUpdate();
}
```